# Why my android app freezes with uncaught exception of type std:: bad_alloc?

Tags: android, uncaught-exception

I used **alarm manager** to call a **java** based **SNMP protocol** every few minutes. My application had frozen with the message you can see on the photo. I am interested in knowing what caused this error and why.

[image: My log message]

PS: Sorry for the photo, as pressing PrtScr button was the fastest I could do.